# How can I debug a non-main .NET assembly using dnSpy?

Tags: debugging, decompilation, .net

I am performing a security assessment on a .NET application. dnSpy is a great tool to do this. However, I've reached a module which is not in the "main" section of the program... It is *loaded* by the program (it's a DLL). I need to find out which code calls a class/method from the DLL and one way I thought of doing this is to debug the program. However, I would have to discover manually which functionality I need to perform in the program in order to get it to call this particular class.

Is there a better way to do this? I also tried to search for the text call to the method in the source code but haven't found anything significant. Lastly, in OllyDbg, a user can manually load a DLL using its DLL loader. Is this possible to do in dnSpy or another .NET tool?

Comment: does this DLL contains managed code too?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik yes

Comment: ok, `Analyze` is not enough in this case to see where it's being called from?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik ah that helped - I was not aware of the Analyze command. Took me a bit to find it but I located it in a right-click context menu for the object. There are some values which show nothing under "read by" but I'm skeptical because I'm sure they're used.

Comment: it would be easier to help working with real files as now we are a bit speculating why/why not they are there. Can you attach the files and add a comment one of which class you are looking for usages?